# Graph representation

Tags: data-structures, graph, adjacency-matrix

Given graph, how could i represent it using adj matrix?. I have read lots of tutorials, post, slides, etc but i cant get my head round it, i just need that little push.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every letter-number combination is one node in your graph, i.e., from A0, A1, A2, ... to F5, F6, F7. Your graph has 48 (8 columns times 6 rows in your maze) nodes, so you'll need a 48x48 matrix. If you treat it as boolean, you'll set all fields to false except the ones where there is a connection between two nodes, e.g. A0 to A1 would mean that the A0 row has a true value in the A1 column, and vice versa (because your graph is undirected).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Do you reckon it will be better to use adjacency list in this case. Cuz 48x48 seems a bit redundant (mirror image) and inefficient.

Comment: And this matrix, by its nature, is symmetrical, so any manipulation (and storage, of course) can be done on one of the halves only.

Comment: The degree of each vertex is at most 4, so adjacency list would be A LOT more efficient.

Comment: True, but it's a small graph and a matrix is generally easier to deal with in a program than a list.

Comment: Many languages (Matlab for example) also have efficient sparse-matrix storage

Comment: @Carlucho, for graphs 25x25 it really doesn't matter.  But generally, for mazes, where there's a lot of cells (vertexes) and just a few edges (connections), it's better off with adjacency lists.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my attempt for the first horizontal line of the maze:

```
   A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7
A0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
A1 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
A2 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
A3 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
A4 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
A5 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
A6 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
A7 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

So you can see from this that your going to end up with a symmetrical matrix due to the undirected nature of your edges and that its going to be sparsely populated.

EDIT: **Matrix vs Lists**

The wikipedia entry for [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) has some good points on the algorithmic benefits of each.

EDIT:

[Wikipedia entry for Adjacency Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) :+)

Comment: thanks for your effort buddy. I was confused because the way i was doing it was not symmetrical so i was pretty sure it was wrong. But when i thought of the idea A1....F7 i just couldn't believe it. As i asked to Robert; what do you think will be better in this case matrix or adjacency list?

Comment: Due to the nature of your graph, low degree and undirected, i would have thought an edge list would be a good bet. The algorithms you want to apply to the data structure should also influence your decision though.

Comment: hey buddy sorry by mistake i down-voted u it doesn't let me cancel the vote for some reason i guess because edited, can u edit anything in your post that way i can give u back the rep/vote. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: @Binary Nerd: Nice link ;P.... By the way, if you like have a look at a new question i posted related to this, maybe you can give me some tips

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to have 2 `boolean` matrices named `Hor` and `Ver` to track the possibility of horizontal and vertical movement respectively.

`Hor Matrix`: Dimension:`6x9` 
`[X,YZ]` represents the possiblity of a horizontal movement from `[X,Y]` to `[X,Z]` on the real board.
`-1` represents the boundary

example: `[A,01]` is `true` and so is `[F,-10]`. But `[B,23]` is `false`.

```
   -10 01 12 23 34 45 56 67 7-1
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Similarly

`Ver Matrix`: Dimension: `7x8`
`[XY,Z]` represents the possiblity of a vertical movement from `[X,Z]` to `[Y,Z]` on the real board.
`Capital o` in the row represent boundary.
example: `[DE,0]` is `true` and so is `[BC,7]`. But `[CD,0]` is `false`.

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

OA
AB
BC
CD
DE
EF
FO
```